# Do we need to read index file every time we do query?

Tags: python, django, search, dictionary

Im implementing search in python for **django**.

In my Query class i alter the position value of the index, which in turn alters the instance data, If i use the same instance of the query object every time, it alters the temporary dictionary and if i do the same query the second time it results to something else.
But, by having a new instance of the query index, i.e getting the index from the file every time, it works fine, i want to know whether i can make a read only Dictionary or make the instance not alter the Dictionary data.

```
def getPosIntersection(self, docID, terms):
    for ID in docID:
        for term in terms:
            for actualTerm in term:
                if ID == actualTerm[0]:
                    self.posIntersectionSet.append(actualTerm[1])

        print "DOCID -> %s" % (docID)        
        print "posIntersectionSet -> %s" % (self.posIntersectionSet)

        intersection = self.posIntersectionSet[0]
        for index, pos in enumerate(self.posIntersectionSet):
            if index > 0:
                for secondIndex, val in enumerate(pos):
                    pos[secondIndex] = pos[secondIndex] - index

            intersection = set(intersection).intersection(pos)

        if intersection:
            if ID not in self.presentDocs:
                print "Pos intersection -> %s" % intersection
                self.presentDocs.append(ID)
```

Here on line 15 im altering the data which is in turn altering the Dictionary instance of the other class variable which i'm passing, How do i make the Dictionary read only and change only its instance.

Answer Found:
I implemented a read only Dictionary and the values were intact, Thank you

Comment: Share some code please.

Comment: I got the solution, Thank you,